# How can I make this plot/diagram in LaTeX?

Tags: pgfplots, plot

[image: Diagram]

Hi, can someone help me make this plot in LaTeX?

Comment: Welcome to TeX-SE! What have you tried? `\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[stealth-stealth] (0,4) node[above]{payoff} |- (5,0) node[below] {$S(2)$};
\draw (2,0) node[below]{$K$} -- ++ (2,3) coordinate[pos=0.8] (aux1) node[above,align=center](alm) {alm\\ call};
\draw (2,0) to[out=60,in=-90]   coordinate[pos=0.8] (aux2) (3,3) node[left=1.5cm,align=center](pft){...\\ call};
\draw[-stealth,shorten >=3pt] (alm.-170) to[bend right] (aux1);
\draw[-stealth,shorten >=3pt] (pft) to[bend right] (aux2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The purpose of this site is not to let someone translate screen shots into LaTeX code. You will find out it is much more satisfying to do these things yourself. The following, which I made a community Wiki, does something like tha.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \draw[stealth-stealth] (0,4) node[above]{payoff} |- (5,0) node[below] {$S(2)$};
 \draw (2,0) node[below]{$K$} -- ++ (2,3) coordinate[pos=0.8] (aux1) node[above,align=center](alm) {alm\\ call};
 \draw (2,0) to[out=60,in=-90]   coordinate[pos=0.8] (aux2) (3,3)
 node[left=1.5cm,align=center](pft){boosted\\ call};
 \draw[-stealth,shorten >=3pt] (alm.-170) to[bend right] (aux1);
 \draw[-stealth,shorten >=3pt] (pft) to[bend right] (aux2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1 for community wiki. :-)